# Using Less than operator in SELECT query within batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am doing the below in my batch file and it is giving me ORA error when using " < 10" in SELECT statement.

Error coming in batchfile: "System cannot find the file specified" 
In output.txt, only this much is being printed, and not the complete statement: 
select 'X' from dual
exit

```
echo select 'X' from dual > output.txt
echo where months_between(sysdate,to_date('20130715','YYYYMMDD')) < 10 ; >> output.txt
echo exit >> output.txt
findstr "X" output.txt>nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto test_proc
```

How to go about rectifying this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `^` to escape the <

```
echo where months_between(sysdate,to_date('20130715','YYYYMMDD')) ^< 10 ; >> output.txt
```

as found [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)